# alternative of `die()` in php

Tags: php, die

I have the following script

```
<?php
      echo "I am alive<br>";
      die("I am dying<br>");
      echo ("Dead");

?>
```

The output that I get is

```
I am alive
I am dying
```

Is there any way (alternative/substitute of `die()`) using which the execution of the remaining script be continued?

**EDIT** :

Sorry I have got what I wanted and have voted to close the question. Please neglect the question.

Comment: What do you want the function to do, besides print something?  The whole point of die is to terminate the script.

Comment: You are looking for a command to terminate script execution that doesn't terminate script execution? I've got one for you: ` ; `   ;)

Comment: can you elaborate on what you want to achieve with this? Do you want to set up an alternative way of handling errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the motives behind your question lie with error handling you might want to have a look at try/catch structures in PHP.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 3):

You can use [trigger_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php):

```
<?php
  echo "I am alive<br>";
  trigger_error("I am dying<br>");
  echo ("Dead");
?>
```

Output:

```
I am alive
Notice: I am dying in ... on line 3
Dead
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run script after result is returned to the user try this:

```
    while (ob_get_level () != 0) {
        ob_end_clean ();
    }

    header ("Connection: close\r\n");
    header ("Content-Encoding: none\r\n");
    ignore_user_abort (true);
    ob_start ();

    // do stuff that should be returned here

    header ("Content-Length: ".ob_get_length ());
    ob_end_flush ();
    flush ();

    // do rest here
```